# Can you simplify for loops?

Tags: python

This compares the values in both lists for common numbers.

```
 a = [1, 2, 2, ]
 b = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12]
 c = a + b
 new = []

 for i in c:
    if i not in new:
        new.append(i)

 print(new)
```

Why is `new = []` necessary? Is there no way to figure this out with just `c`?

Comment: `set(c)` is better, but removes order.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do.  If you want to "compare the values in both lists for common numbers," it seems you want the intersection of the two sets.  The code you have above produces the union of the two sets.

Comment: Yes, union would be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all your values are hashable (`int` is), you can avoid the explicit loop by converting to an ordered dictionary type (to dedupe), then back to `list`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = [1, 2, 2, ]
b = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12]
new = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(a + b))
print(new)
```

On modern Python (CPython/PyPy 3.6 as an implementation detail, any interpreter on 3.7+ as a language guarantee), `dict` itself is insertion ordered, so no import is necessary, and the definition of `new` can shorten to:

```
new = list(dict.fromkeys(a + b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this one:

```
a = [1, 2, 2]
b = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12]
c = a + b
list(set(c))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Note that using `set` here loses order.

Comment: Interesting. I was not aware of the set() function. Are there any advantages of using the for function rather than set?

Comment: Yes, that's the drawback of using `set()`.

Comment: @AnacondianPython: The advantage of `set` (and my `dict` based solution as well) is that they're `O(1)` to perform insertion and membership testing, and naturally unique. `list`s are `O(n)` for membership testing (amortized `O(1)` for insertion at the end at least), so the loop you used is `O(n**2)` (`n` for outer loop, times `n` for each membership test), where a `set` or `dict` based solution is only `O(n)` (`n` to loop over input, but membership test/insertion remains `1` work). Going from 100 input items to 1000 input items would increase work 10x for `set`/`dict`, or 100x for your `list`.